# How to solve this trig equation with Mathematica?

Tags: equation-solving

The `Reduce` command of Mathematica is powerful. However, both `Reduce` and `FindInstance` are not able to solve
$$\sqrt{18 | \tan (x)| +6 | \cot (x)| +21}+\sqrt{4 | \tan (4 x)| +12 | \cot (4 x)| +19}=3 \sqrt{3}+7 $$
over the reals running without any response during a long time. I solve it in such a way. First, the result of

```
Plot[Sqrt[21 + 18*RealAbs[Tan[x]] + 6*RealAbs[Cot[x]]] + 
Sqrt[19 + 4*RealAbs[Tan[4 x]] + 12*RealAbs[Cot[4 x]]] - 7 - 
3*Sqrt[3], {x, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}]
```

shows  two roots near $-0.5$ and $0.5$. Now

```
FindRoot[Sqrt[21 + 18*RealAbs[Tan[x]] + 6*RealAbs[Cot[x]]] + 
Sqrt[19 + 4*RealAbs[Tan[4 x]] + 12*RealAbs[Cot[4 x]]] - 7 - 
3*Sqrt[3], {x, 0.5}]
```

> `{x -> 0.523599}`

and

```
6*0.5235987628872519
```

> `3.14159`

suggest that $-\frac \pi 6$ and  $\frac \pi 6$ are the solutions on $(-\frac \pi 2,-\frac \pi 2)$. The verification confirms it. How to prove with Mathematica these are the only solutions of the equation under consideration on that interval? What are other ways to symbolically solve that equation with Mathematica?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
eqn = Sqrt[21 + 18 Abs[Tan[x]] + 6 Abs[Cot[x]]] + Sqrt[19 + 4 Abs[Tan[4 x]] + 12 Abs[Cot[4 x]]] - 7 - 3 Sqrt[3] == 0;
RootReduce@Reduce[ExpandAll[eqn /. x -> ArcTan[t], Trig -> True], t, Reals] /. t -> Tan[x]
Solve[% && -Pi/2 < x < Pi/2, x]
```

> $\tan (x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\lor \tan (x)=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$

> $\left\{\left\{x\to -\frac{\pi }{6}\right\},\left\{x\to \frac{\pi }{6}\right\}\right\}$

Comment: Sorry for the delay in reply. I was out of MMA some time.

Answer (score 5):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

eqn = Sqrt[21 + 18 Abs[Tan[x]] + 6 Abs[Cot[x]]] + 
    Sqrt[19 + 4 Abs[Tan[4 x]] + 12 Abs[Cot[4 x]]] == 3 Sqrt[3] + 7;
```

Since we are dealing with reals,

```
eqn2 = eqn /. Abs[t_] :> Sqrt[t^2]

(* Sqrt[21 + 6 Sqrt[Cot[x]^2] + 18 Sqrt[Tan[x]^2]] + Sqrt[
  19 + 12 Sqrt[Cot[4 x]^2] + 4 Sqrt[Tan[4 x]^2]] == 7 + 3 Sqrt[3] *)
```

Finding approximate solutions

```
(sol = NSolve[{eqn2, -Pi/2 < x < Pi/2}, x, Reals]) // 
  AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.119084, {{x -> -0.523599}, {x -> 0.523599}}} *)
```

Converting to algebraic numbers,

```
sol2 = sol /. r_Real :> RootApproximant[r/Pi]*Pi

(* {{x -> -(π/6)}, {x -> π/6}} *)
```

Verifying that the algebraic numbers are the actual solutions

```
eqn /. sol2

(* {True, True} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Plotting this function with almost your code:

```
Plot[Sqrt[21 + 18*RealAbs[Tan[x]] + 6*RealAbs[Cot[x]]] + 
  Sqrt[19 + 4*RealAbs[Tan[4 x]] + 12*RealAbs[Cot[4 x]]] - 7 - 
  3*Sqrt[3], {x, 0.5, 0.55}, PlotRange -> {-0.0005, 0.001}]
```

we get the following:

[image]

That is, the solution is either in the minimum point or somewhere in its close vicinity.

Let us find the point of minimum for `x>0`:

```
    eq = (D[Sqrt[21 + 18*RealAbs[Tan[x]] + 6*RealAbs[Cot[x]]] + 
          Sqrt[19 + 4*RealAbs[Tan[4 x]] + 12*RealAbs[Cot[4 x]]] - 7 - 
          3*Sqrt[3], x] // Simplify[#, x > 0] &) == 0
FindRoot[eq, {x, 0.5}]

(* {x -> 0.523599} *)
```

Now, let us use this solution as a starting point for the solution of the initial equation:

```
FindRoot[
 Sqrt[21 + 18*RealAbs[Tan[x]] + 6*RealAbs[Cot[x]]] + 
   Sqrt[19 + 4*RealAbs[Tan[4 x]] + 12*RealAbs[Cot[4 x]]] - 7 - 
   3*Sqrt[3] == 0, {x, 0.5235987755982988`}]

(*  {x -> 0.523599}  *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: Sorry, I don't find your approximate solution useful.

Comment: @user64494 That's up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my answer. The plot suggests that the LHS is greater than or equal to the RHS. In view of it I find

```
Minimize[{Sqrt[21 + 18*y + 6/y], y >= 0}, y]
```

> `{Sqrt[21 + 12 Sqrt[3]], {y -> 1/Sqrt[3]}}`

and

```
Minimize[{Sqrt[19 + 4*z + 12/z], z >= 0}, z]
```

> `{Sqrt[19 + 8 Sqrt[3]], {z -> Sqrt[3]}}`

Indeed,

```
FullSimplify[Sqrt[21 + 12 Sqrt[3]]+Sqrt[19 + 8 Sqrt[3]]-7-3*Sqrt[3]]
```

> `0`

Finally,

```
Reduce[RealAbs[Tan[x]] == 1/Sqrt[3]&&RealAbs[Tan[4*x]] == Sqrt[3], x, Reals]
```

> `(C[1] \[Element]  Integers && (x == -((5 \[Pi])/6) + 2 \[Pi] C[1] ||  x == \[Pi]/6 + 2 \[Pi] C[1])) || (C[1] \[Element]  Integers && (x == -(\[Pi]/6) + 2 \[Pi] C[1] ||  x == (5 \[Pi])/6 + 2 \[Pi] C[1]))`

Comment: Mathematica knows and uses the above method, but the equation under consideration is too difficult for her.